# Java Comparable is not working in Java PriorityQueue (PriorityQueue is not sorted based on a particular field)

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator, comparable

I am trying to push some object inside a priority queue and I want them to be sorted based on the pathCost so the lowest pathCost would always be on the top of the queue.

```
    Queue<Node> frontier = new PriorityQueue<>(7, Node.pathComparator);
    Node n1 = new Node("z");n1.setPathCost(13);
    Node n2 = new Node("a");n2.setPathCost(12);
    Node n3 = new Node("f");n3.setPathCost(65);
    Node n4 = new Node("h");n4.setPathCost(10);

    frontier.add(n1);
    frontier.add(n2);
    frontier.add(n3);
    frontier.add(n4);

    System.out.println(frontier);
```

Here is the implementation of Comparable in my Node class:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Node node) {
    return (this.pathCost - node.pathCost);
}

public static Comparator<Node> pathComparator = new Comparator<Node>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Node n1, Node n2) {
    return (int) (n1.getPathCost() - n2.getPathCost());
    }
};
```

When output the queue it is not sorted based on pathCost! Does anybody know where is the problem?
My output: [h, a, f, z]

Comment: The problem is you didn't read the Javadoc. ;)  PrirotiyQueue only guarantees the first element is sorted.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! such a simple and tricky point! :)
@PeterSmith

Comment: PriorityQueue assumes you only care about the next() element which AFAIK speeds up the performance. It does mean however that when you iterate over the collection it is not sorted.